How to passing className to child component in react
my Parent
 <Button color="green" value="Create" />
 <Button color="red" value="Create" />

my child component
const Button = ({ color, value }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={`text-white bg-gradient-to-r from-${color}-500 via-${color}-600 
      to-${color}-700 hover:bg-gradient-to-br focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none 
      focus:ring-${color}-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center 
      me-2 mb-2`}
    >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
};

if i console.log(color), the className is fine with my passed color value, but the style doesn't appear in button, if i type manual className on button in child component without props, the style is works
I would be very grateful if anyone is willing to help

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Have the entire class in the variable you pass to className like
const Button = ({ color, value }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={`text-white bg-gradient-to-r ${color} hover:bg-gradient-to-br focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center 
      me-2 mb-2`}
    >

<Button color="from-green-500 via-green-600 to-green-700 focus:ring-green-300 " value="Create" />
<Button color="from-red-500 via-red-600 to-red-700 focus:ring-red-300 " value="Create" />


Have a dictionary for color to Tailwind class names:
const Button = ({ color, value }) => {
  const DICTIONARY = {
    green: 'from-green-500 via-green-600 to-green-700 focus:ring-green-300',
    red: 'from-red-500 via-red-600 to-red-700 focus:ring-red-300',
    // …
  };
  // …
  return (
  <button
    type="button"
    className={`text-white bg-gradient-to-r ${DICTIONARY[color]} hover:bg-gradient-to-br focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center 
    me-2 mb-2`}


safelist the classes, if you have a limited number of known colors:
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^from-(red|green|blue)-500$/ },
    { pattern: /^via-(red|green|blue)-600$/ },
    { pattern: /^to-(red|green|blue)-700$/ },
    {
      pattern: /^ring-(red|green|blue)-300$/,
      variants: ['focus']
    },
    // …
  ],
  // …
];




Thank you very much, finally I know the concept. At first I thought I could make a short dynamic style with passing props, but it turns out that tailwind can't do that yet.
